# Is there any sense in carrying assembled enclosed electronics in a static-shielding bag?

Tags: protection, esd, shielding, cases, metal

Say I have a Raspberry Pi enclosed in a metal case, such as [this](https://www.kksb-cases.com/uploads/1/0/1/8/101880880/kksb-okt-2017-1_1_orig.jpg).

Would it offer any additional level protection if I put it in a static-shielding antistatic bag whenever I carry it around (e.g. before putting it in a bag or cardboard box)?

Does this offer any additional level of protection, for example from ESD damage?
Otherwise, does it, maybe, create some potential risk I may not be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once it's enclosed in a case, there's not much need to put it inside an ESD bag - these are used when there's bare PCB exposed. The bag may add a very minor level of protection for the connector sockets however the device is much more likely to be damaged once it's in use out of the packaging.

There's no harm in putting it in an ESD protective bag, however the benefits of putting an already-enclosed product in one are negligible.

Comment: Also correctly manufactured products will have protection on all sockets/ports. If you know where to look at the Pi PCB you can find them.

Comment: Ok, I just had a spare static-shielding bag, and I thought I might use it for that, as I don't move naked electronics around too much anyway. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

> Would it offer any additional level protection if I put it in a
>   static-shielding antistatic bag whenever I carry it around (e.g.
>   before putting it in a bag or cardboard box)?

Yes, you do get additional protection.

Exposed potentials (such as those on connectors) can be a conduit for ESD. If a potential is developed (especially the thousands of V/m that can be developed from clothing) across the part then connectors such as USB, or Ethernet can be affected. An ESD bag will prevent these electric fields from affecting the inside of the bag. (make sure you don't use the polypropolene (or pink bags) as they are intended for shipping, and the conductive layer wears off, use the mylar metalized bags).

That being said the connectors are partially connected by the shields on the outside of the conductors, an electric field or ESD event is most likely going to conduct through the shield (which is traditionally connected to ground on the PCB).

It really depends on how much the product is worth protecting. The probability of you degrading an enclosed PCB is very low, but it's not zero. If you value it then protect it in an ESD bag.

Answer (score 1):

It will help protect the paintwork, keep lint out, and maybe even protect it from liquid spills if it is closed.